# Redirect API in PHP with POST data

Tags: php, redirect

I created a new API that receives XML data in POST and responds in XML. The link is

```
localhost/api/rate.php
```

Now, users were already accessing the old version of this API using the following link,

```
localhost/rate.php
```

I need to redirect to the new link when the user hits the old link and displays the response from the new API to the user.

If I user `header(location)` the POST data does not get sent to the new API, so I'm out of options.

Comment: Why don't you just make them both point to the same function? Also have you considered using something like Laravel to make your API?

Answer (score 0):

you could do like this:

your rate.php:

```
<?php

function redirect($url) {
  $html = "<html><body><form id='form' action='$url' method='post'>";
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $html .= "<input type='hidden' name='$key' value='$value'>";
  }
  $html .= "</form><script>document.getElementById('form').submit();</script>";
  $html .= "</body></html>";
  print($html);
}

redirect('api/rate.php');
```

or safer:

```
.htaccess file with:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^rate.php(.*)$ /api/rate.php$1 [R=302]
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: This also breaks the back button.